# Redirect/forward service from port as page

Tags: php, python, nginx

I've set up simple LEMP (ubuntu, nginx, mysql, php) server using no-ip: http://koferta.no-ip.biz/ As you can see there are some services/servers/daemons running on various ports.

Main Question is how to make those services available like pages, i.e. `http://koferta.no-ip.biz/deluge/` on port 80 instead of service on port, i.e. `http://koferta.no-ip.biz:8112` so i can disable forwarding ports, make links more user-friendly etc.

As far as I know I cannot use vhosts/server-blocks because of using free account at no-ip.
Is there way to accomplish such effect using php, python or anything? Maybe some trick with nginx? Or only solution is to paid account at some dyndns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nginx:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /deluge/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8112;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunatly only one site and one service work as expected. Only plex media server and deluge have some problems, but now i know where to look for answers.

Comment: For wordpress i get  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, for plex media server I need something like ` proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:32400/web/index.html;` but qouted line results in 404, and with deluge theres `No Such Resource No such child resource.` So any further help will be appreciated, and i'm going to look in internets for more info ;)